# Remove comments from HTML templates using Maven

Tags: java, html, maven, web-applications, thymeleaf

Is there a standard and easy way how to remove comments from HTML templates (Thymeleaf) using a Maven plugin ? It would be nice if it can do this conventionally only for `<body>` content and leave browser hints in `<head` untouched.

I know I can filter Maven resources or use Thymeleaf comments  by I am looking for ready solution.

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved in Maven by several techniques. The commonality in them being being the regular expression based replacement:

[1](https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/) Maven Regex Replacement using the `[Maven Replacer Plugin][1]`

[2](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/09/20/trimming-comments-in-html-documents-using-apache-ant/) Maven Antrun Plugin 
Have an ANT target to replace the commented html. For example:

```
<fileset id="html.fileset"
    dir="${build.dir}"
    includes="**/*.jsp, **/*.php, **/*.html"/>

<!-- HTML Comments -->
<replaceregexp replace="" flags="g"
    match="\&lt;![ \r\n\t]*(--([^\-]|[\r\n]|-[^\-])*--[ \r\n\t]*)\&gt;">
    <fileset refid="html.fileset"/>
</replaceregexp>

<!-- Empty lines -->
<replaceregexp match="^\s+[\r\n]" replace="" flags="mg">
    <fileset refid="html.fileset"/>
</replaceregexp>
```

Ant target Source: [Link](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/09/20/trimming-comments-in-html-documents-using-apache-ant/) 
Invoke this target using the Maven-antrun-plugin.

Comment: Beware of the problems html parsing using regex MAY give: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1542723